# Angular2 throws error while use the node modules reference

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

I am getting error while i use the angular2 from node_modules.

How do I fix? What I missed in my html file?

Please give me a git repo for angular2 for offline development.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `tools/typescript.js` and pointing your angular.js to `node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js` instead

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I tried the same. but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I missed that the console was throwing other errors, too. I use Karma to run unit tests for an angular2 app and borrowed much of my test setup from the angular2 project itself.

Karma loads the files and since I'm using them for test, I load out of `node_modules`. The first four must be loaded first and in this order before bringing in angular2 and other libs:

```
'node_modules/angular2/node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur-runtime.js',
'node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader-sans-promises.js',
'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
'node_modules/angular2/**/*.js
```

Then a test helper configures System:

```
System.config({
    ...
    paths: {
        'angular2/*': 'node_modules/angular2/*.js',
        'rx': 'node_modules/angular2/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.js'
    }
    ...
});
```

Hope that helps. You may want to pull the files you need into a `lib` directory if you're serving them with your code.

Comment: I added those line. No use.. that's why I commented. :(

Comment: Ah, and `require` is throwing a fit, too. I'll edit my response to provide more of my set up. I use mine to run Karma unit tests for an Angular2 app.

Comment: hi.. Thanks for your help.  I could not find the file es6-module-loader-sans-promises.js in my Node Modules folder. i have used the following command to install the es6. 'npm install es6-module-loader --save'